# can't get ucfirst() to work on a variable

Tags: php

I have made a code that takes the first name and last name from an email, the $firstname is uppercase but $lastname is not. Why?

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$email = "test.testt@testing.com";
$firstname = ucfirst(strtok(strtok($email, "@"), "."));
$lastname = substr(strtok(strtok($email, "@"), ".") . ' ' . strtok("."), strrpos(strtok(strtok($email, "@"), ".") . ' ' . strtok("."), ' '));
$lastname = ucfirst($lastname);
        
echo $firstname.$lastname;
?> 
 
</body>
</html>
```

**Output: Test testt**

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `$lastname` __starts with space__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the actual problem being the space, your code does a lot of searching and chopping strings up.

You could simplify it by using `explode()` with first the `@` and then a `.`.  Then using `ucfirst` on each part of the last operation...

```
$names = explode("@", $email);
// Get first 2 parts of name and split it by the .
[$firstname, $lastname] = explode(".", $names[0], 2);
$firstname = ucfirst($firstname);
$lastname = ucfirst($lastname);
echo $firstname . ' ' . $lastname;
```

Answer (score 0):

The space was indeed the problem, I fixed it by using `$lastname = ucfirst(str_replace(' ', '', $lastname));`

Comment: maybe trim() function will bei your friend instead auf str_replace, like `$lastname = ucfirst(trim($lastname))`